# Send email with own domain in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, email

I'm trying to implement automatic emails from my android application. While i'm using @gmail, all works fine. But if i try to set the address and smtp of my own domain it stops working.
Here's my code:

```
public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
    
    public GMailSender(String user, String password) {
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";
        props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");

        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
    }

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
    }

    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {
        try{
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/html"));

            message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setDataHandler(handler);
            if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
            else
                message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));
            Transport.send(message);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

How can i do to send emails using my own domain (example@mydomain.com)?

EDIT:
As Simon Degn said, I set the parameters of my domain’s provider. Also, I wrote a page in my APIs for sending the mail, avoiding the sending from the application client keeping my credentials less exposed.

Comment: Do you have a smtp-server set up for your domain?

Comment: No. Is it because of it?

Comment: The domain itself is not able to send emails. The domain is just the address for a server-destination. If you are using a web hosting service like GoDaddy or Squarespace, just search for a guide how to set up a custom email and smtp for your domain.